# How to install Tensorflow federated directly from GitHub or local download?

Tags: tensorflow, github, tensorflow-federated

I want to have access to features from TensorFlow federated (tff.python.research) which aren't present with the pip3 install method.

I'm working on a remote server that does not have bazel, thus I cannot build from source. Are there other ways to get and install the latest working version of TFF from its GitHub REPO?

(https://github.com/tensorflow/federated)

Answer (score 1):

To install the latest **Tensorflow 2.0 federated**, you may follow the steps below.

**Install TensorFlow Federated using pip**

1. Install the Python development environment

```
On Ubuntu:
  $ sudo apt update
  $ sudo apt install python3-dev python3-pip  # Python 3
  $ sudo pip3 install --upgrade virtualenv    # system-wide install
```

```
On macOS:
  $ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
  $ export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
  $ brew update
  $ brew install python  # Python 3
  $ sudo pip3 install --upgrade virtualenv  # system-wide install
```

2. Create a virtual environment

```
$ virtualenv --python python3 "venv"
$ source "venv/bin/activate"
(venv) $ pip install --upgrade pip


Note: To exit the virtual environment, run deactivate.
```

3. Install the TensorFlow Federated pip package.

```
(venv) $ pip install --upgrade tensorflow_federated
```

4. (Optional) Test Tensorflow Federated.

```
(venv) $ python -c "import tensorflow_federated as tff; print(tff.federated_computation(lambda: 'Hello World')())"
```

**Build the TensorFlow Federated pip package**

1. Install the Python development environment.

```
On Ubuntu:
 $ sudo apt update
 $ sudo apt install python3-dev python3-pip  # Python 3
 $ sudo pip3 install --upgrade virtualenv  # system-wide install

On macOS:
 $ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
 $ export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
 $ brew update
 $ brew install python  # Python 3
 $ sudo pip3 install --upgrade virtualenv  # system-wide install
```

2. Install Bazel
   Install Bazel, the **build tool used to compile Tensorflow Federated**.
3. Clone the Tensorflow Federated repository.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/federated.git
$ cd "federated"
```

4. Create a virtual environment.

```
$ virtualenv --python python3 "venv"
$ source "venv/bin/activate"
(venv) $ pip install --upgrade pip

Note: To exit the virtual environment, run deactivate.
```

5. Install Tensorflow Federated dependencies.

```
(venv) $ pip install --requirement "requirements.txt"
```

6. (Optional) Test Tensorflow Federated.

```
(venv) $ bazel test //tensorflow_federated/...
```

8. Create a new project.

```
$ mkdir "/tmp/project"
$ cd "/tmp/project"

$ virtualenv --python python3 "venv"
$ source "venv/bin/activate"
(venv) $ pip install --upgrade pip

Note: To exit the virtual environment run deactivate.
```

9. Install the pip package.

```
(venv) $ pip install --upgrade "/tmp/tensorflow_federated/tensorflow_federated-"*".whl"
```

10. Test Tensorflow Federated.

```
(venv) $ python -c "import tensorflow_federated as tff; print(tff.federated_computation(lambda: 'Hello World')())"
```

**Reference:** https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/install

Comment: Thank you but is there another method without bazel?

Comment: Hi @Michael24, the first method specified installs the Tensorflow Federated using pip.

Comment: There are some features that I would like to access that is not present with the pip install such (tff.python.research).

Is there a way to access all of TFF without using bazel?